# When I route my controller it can't work

Tags: php, laravel

I created a controller myindex by artisan command when I route it gives an error.

```
Controller:
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class myindex extends Controller
   {
    public function index(){
    return view('newpage.blade.php');
   }
   }
```

newpage.blade.php

```
  {!! Form::open() !!}
  {!! Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address') !!}
  {!! Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true) !!}
  {!! Form::radio('radio_name', 'value', true) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

route:

Route::get('newpage','myindex@index');

And the error

InvalidArgumentException
  View [newpage.blade.php] not found.

C:\wamp64\www\todoapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php
      /**
       * Find the given view in the list of paths.
       *
       * @param  string  $name
       * @param  array   $paths
       * @return string
       *
       * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
       */
       protected function findInPaths($name, $paths)
        {
        foreach ((array) $paths as $path) {
            foreach ($this->getPossibleViewFiles($name) as $file) {
                if ($this->files->exists($viewPath = $path.'/'.$file)) {
                    return $viewPath;
                }
            }
          }

```
     throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found.");
   }

  /**
   * Get an array of possible view files.
   *
    * @param  string  $name
   * @return array
   */
   protected function getPossibleViewFiles($name)
  {
       return array_map(function ($extension) use ($name) {
          return str_replace('.', '/', $name).'.'.$extension;
      }, $this->extensions);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To return `view` from `controller`, you just have to provide view name without `.blade.php`

So do this:

```
return view('newpage');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not return view.  In Laravel the view method is use to return a page and data.
The view can take two parameters. The first is the page which automatically add .blade.php and the second is the data in array.
Example.
     $data = array(
         "title" => "The title of the page"
      )
      return view ('thepagename',$data);

Answer (score 0):

just remove .blade.php :D

```
return view('newpage');
```

laravel engine is deal with .blade.php as view

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur only when the given view path is incorrect. Another thing you don't need to tell explicitly tell **.blade.php** laravel automatically search for that.

Answer (score 0):

Return views by the view name without `.blade.php`:

```
return view('newpage');
```

If your view is in another folder inside the views folder, then you can use the dot notation to identify sub-folders. For instance, if your view is located deeper in the views directory, like `views/first_folder/another_folder/even_another/newpage.blade.php`, then you will get the view this way:

```
return view('first_folder.another_folder.even_another.newpage');
```